# Can I create a specific ringtone for email from specific people?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, gmail, notifications, audio

Is there any way at all to set it up so that I can have a different notification sound for different email senders?

In other words, if I get an email from Fred, can I have a different notification than an email from Jane?

I know how to set up filters within Gmail, but I can't determine if there is any way to connect that to the notification sound on my phone.

I also know that different ringtones can be set when getting phone calls from different people, based on their entry in the contact list. However, there does not seem to be any kind of option in the contacts interface to do the same thing with emails.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is funny you ask this since Gmail just came out today with functionality that allows for different ringtones to be set for different labels ([using custom label notifications.](http://www.droid-life.com/2011/07/28/gmail-app-for-android-receives-update-to-2-3-5-performance-improvements-and-custom-label-notifications-included/))  This might not be perfect since you would need to specify a label per contact to make it work, but it could serve your needs.

Comment: Awesome! This looks like it will do what I need. I don't think I really need the granularity of a per-user notification, and grouping with filters will suffice.

Comment: Google must be listening :) You ask on July 26 and they release it on July 27.  Good stuff.